# Parse a faultString from response of AdWords API

Tags: ruby, savon, google-ads-api

I am developing an AdWords API client on Ruby using Google's gems `google-adwords-api` and `ads-common` (which utilizes `savon`).

When some AdWords policy is violated, Savon raises an exception with violation description in its `message`. For example, on violating trademark policies:

```
[PolicyViolationError{
  super=PolicyViolationError.POLICY_ERROR @ operations[0].operand.ad.headline,
  key=PolicyViolationKey{policyName=trademark,violatingText=Xerox},
  externalPolicyName=Trademarked Term,
  externalPolicyUrl=,
  externalPolicyDescription=Due to trademark reasons, we do not allow advertisers to use 'Xerox' in their Google AdWords ads. This term may be trademarked either for a certain product or service category and may apply only in certain countries you have targeted.

  ,
  isExemtable=true,
  violatingParts=[Part{index=0, length=5}]}]
```

I formatted it for clarity, but originally, there are only two line breakes after "targeted.", the rest is one line without breakes and with spaces only after commas, aroung "@" and in natural language text.

How do I parse this kind of message with Ruby in most simple way? My hope is that this is some markup language and there is a gem for it. So I don't want to use regular expressions if there is a more right way.

Comment: is it a string or a structure? If it's a string I'd use a regular expression. Which data do you need to extract?

Comment: A string. RegEx is the utlimate answer, and probably I'll use it. I was just hoping somebody will recognize the markup language and tell me what gem to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It lied in Google's gem `google-adwords-api`. The exception raised was of class `AdwordsApi::V201309::AdGroupAdService::ApiException`. Besides the `message` attribute it has `errors` attribute containing the same message in form of a structure. So no need to parse the strange markup syntax.

```
> pp e.errors
[{:field_path=>"operations[0].operand.ad.headline",
  :trigger=>nil,
  :error_string=>"PolicyViolationError.POLICY_ERROR",
  :api_error_type=>"PolicyViolationError",
  :key=>{:policy_name=>"trademark", :violating_text=>"Sony"},
  :external_policy_name=>"Trademarked Term",
  :external_policy_url=>nil,
  :external_policy_description=>
   "Due to trademark reasons, we do not allow advertisers to use 'Sony' in their Google AdWords ads. This term may be trademarked either for a certain product or service category and may apply only in certain countries you have targeted.\n\n",
  :is_exemptable=>true,
  :violating_parts=>[{:index=>0, :length=>4}],
  :xsi_type=>"PolicyViolationError"}]
```

A nice hash from which I can pull `policy_name`, `violating_text` and other details.